# How to prevent rebuild in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a problem now, that is, a **Row** widget contains many pictures，as follows:

```
class PageA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        // I don't want it rebuild every time
        child: Row(
          children: _getImageList(),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.forward),
        onPressed: () {
          // Navigator to PageB
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageB()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  // add asset images to list
  List<Widget> _getImageList() {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      list.add(Image.asset('assets/images/$i.jpg'));
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

When I return to the **PageA** from **PageB**, the **PageA** will rebuild, but I don't want to rebuild the **Row** widget in the **PageA**, Because it contains many pictures. is there any way to do it? Thanks!!!

Comment: Try to add more code so we can understand what actually you are trying to do.Are those pictures coming from network request?

Comment: @RopAliMunshi  pictures coming from assets folder

Answer (score 0):

To better performance split you `_getImageList` method to another Widget.

Answer (score 0):

use [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html)